# Is there a software to automatically crop a scan of multiple images? ( Windows 10 )

Tags: photo-editing, software, cropping, software-recommendation, windows

I want to digitize my old family albums using a scanner and there are lots of photos in them. Thus far, my method has been to scan 4 images at a time and then manually cropping them in a simple editor like paint 3d. This has been pretty time consuming as each scan is followed by 4 crop operations. Scanning each image individually would possibly be even more time consuming.
I'm on windows 10. Is there any software (other than photoshop) or simple plugin that does this job?

Comment: Scanning multiple photos may be slower. When you have one photo, there is one single gesture to tuck the picture in a corner of the scanner. You can train yourself to repeat this without even thinking. With 4 pictures, you have four different gestures.

Answer (score 0):

On my phone I use Microsoft Lens. Here are some similar results to Microsoft Lens that are for Windows - https://alternativeto.net/software/office-lens/?platform=windows